# Placing wide fullpage figure in a two-column document

Tags: floats, two-column, revtex

this is my first question.
In a two-column document I need to insert five high images (approx. 22cm in one figure, I am using all of the page width. I'm fitting a caption below the images.
I am using `figure*` environment. During compilation I'am getting message:

*LaTeX Warning: A float is stuck (cannot be placed) on input line 1706.*

*Class revtex4-1 Warning: Deferred float stuck during \clearpage processing.

*! Output routine didn't use all of \box255.*

My guess is that latex is trying to fit two-column text lines on the page and returns error since due to lack of space this is not possible. The best way I imagine would be to have this whole page switched to one-column layout, however workarounds like `\twocolumngrid, \onecolumngrid` did not work. In one column layout the document is compiled successfully.

Please help.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{aastex62}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\usepackage{aas_macros}

\begin{document}
...

\begin{figure*}
   \newcommand\figh{22.5cm}
   \newcommand\figsep{5.pt}

   \includegraphics[height=\figh]{figs/fig1.pdf}\hspace{1pt}\vline\hspace{1pt}
   \includegraphics[height=\figh {figs/fig2.pdf}\hspace{\figsep}\includegraphics[height=\figh]{figs/fig3.pdf}\hspace{\figsep}\hspace{\figsep}
   \includegraphics[height=\figh]{figs/fig4.pdf}\hspace{\figsep}\includegraphics[height=\figh]{figs/fig5.pdf}

   \caption{Figure description}
   \label{fig:tall_wide_fig}
\end{figure*}


...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Maybe trying to have a non-float picture: put `\includegraphics` in a `strip` environment (package `cuted`) and use `\captionof{figure}`.

Comment: @Bernard thank you for your response, however package ```cuted``` seems to be conflicting with other packages I use - I get errors like *Undefined control sequence \subsection* which are frequently used in the document.

Comment: Quite strange … Maybe you can try loading`stfloats`, from the same author. It enables you to use the placement optional arguments `[t]` or `[b]` with figure*.

Comment: @Bernard thanks again; ```stfloats``` does not conflicts with other packages, but optional arguments - ```[t]```, ```[b]```, ```[ht]```, ```[htp]``` - are not working fixing the problem in this case (still getting *Output routine didn't use all of \box255*), however with ```cuted``` package it crashes elsewhere (earlier). I might need a solution that enables me to compile this page with two-column layout turned off.

Comment: Also interesting point - using the ```[H]``` option results in successful compilation, but the page with figures is not included.

Comment: For cuted, I really don't understand: it's done precisely for that: inserting full-width material (not only figures or tables) in a two-column document. Maybe a conflict I didn't know about (I don't use personally aastex). I'll try to see if there's a workaround.

Comment: I can't run your code as I don't have your `figs` files. Are you sure that the figure fits within the page limits, not too wide or too tall?

Comment: @Bernard: for ```cuted``` it seems to be conflicting with aastex62 class that I am required to use: tested with simple document - it compiles with ```\usepackage{cuted}``` when ```documentclass``` is article, but with aastex62 it won't (*Undefined control sequence \end{document}*), unless there is another package needed to make it work. I don't know anything anymore.

Comment: I only have the current aastex63 class and it doesn't conflict… ???

Comment: @Bernard I am not sure why, maybe it crashes due to blank lines

Comment: @PeterWilson Thank you for your response. I think the figures do not exceed the page limits; they are fitted pretty well in one column environment.

Comment: I suspect your figure is too tall to fit on the page.  Try splitting it into three separate `figure*`s.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. With ```\documentclass[twocolumn]{aastex63}``` imported I get parameter ```\dblpagefraction{0.85}``` which - if I understand it correctly - disallows me to have a float covering larger fraction of the page. I cannot override that setting, so I will have to leave it as it is.
Thank you for your time, everyone.